# How to Filter with Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have this Dataframe:

```
          MNR      Price    LIMIT   LIMIT1
0      03M7401     49.76    0.0    1.0
1    LCA94237B     16.56    5.0    1.0
2    LCA94237B     55.68    1.0    1.0
3    LCA94237B      8.73   25.0    1.0
4  LCA95038B-1      2.33  100.0  100.0
5  LCA95038B-1      2.08  300.0  100.0
6  LCA95038B-1      2.71   50.0  100.0
7  LCA95038B-1      6.17    9.0  100.0
```

So on the left site  `df['MNR']`  is a Itemnumber.

As you can see I can sometimes `LIMIT`= `LIMIT1`. Can I use a filter to display only the item number where `LIMIT` = `LIMIT1`?

so i want to have this result at the end.

```
          MNR      Price    LIMIT   LIMIT1
0      03M7401     49.76    0.0    1.0
2    LCA94237B     55.68    1.0    1.0
4  LCA95038B-1      2.33  100.0  100.0
```

Or do you have other Ideas how i can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Use `df[df['LIMIT'] == df['LIMIT1']]`

Comment: When I do this i Loose  the first Itemnumber!